# HTML editor in sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

Does anyone know if there is a sonata widget to show an HTML editor in the edit form? I'm thinking of using a custom template for that field which integrates an HTML, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Give a try to [IvoryCKEditorBundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle)

Answer (score 1):

There is [SonataFormatterBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter).

Answer (score 0):

I also used [IvoryCKEditorBundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle)

After the initial setup in your project, you can use it easily as below:

```
use Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
           ->add('description', CKEditorType::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you implement it: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html

My code example:

```
source_field -> body => existing entity field
format_field -> formattedBody => create new field in entity
target_field -> body => existing entity field

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
$formMapper
->add('body', 'sonata_formatter_type', array(
'event_dispatcher' =>
     $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getEventDispatcher(),
'format_field' => 'formattedBody',
'format_field_options' => array(
    'choices' => array('richhtml'),
    'data' => 'richhtml',
),
'source_field' => 'body',
'source_field_options' => array(
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'span10',
        'rows' => 20,
    ),
),
'listener' => true,
'target_field' => 'body',
))
```